# How to change webpack-dev-server with other server like express or apache

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js

I have used vue-cli to scaffolding an vue app and now I want to setup a different web server rather then webpack-dev-server because I want a separate configuration file where I can configure the server like node express which I can use for production deployment.

Please suggest is there any way to configure the new server. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For development you should continue using webpack dev server (which is express).

For deployment you can use anything you want, just run:

```
npm run build
```

This will generate bundled javascript files, which you can then deploy anywhere.

Comment: thanks for reply but my concern is can we configure different server for development rather then webpack dev server like apache if yes then from where I can configure it so development environment can use that server.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to use a different development server (in your question you were asking for production). Since webpack is node I don't think it'll run with anything else in Dev mode,like I mentioned it's using express. Even if it was possible I still wouldn't recommend it you would most likely lose hot reloading and express is one of the most lightweight servers anyway. But like I said production will work with anything. Maybe there is a better approach than changing servers in dev mode, can you explain why you want to do that?

Comment: Actually I want fully featured app that have their own app server that have their own control.
Suppose staging  don't any server then I can use it there and same for production also.

Comment: The point of a development server is to have access to tools like hot reloading and source maps, those are tightly coupled to the webpack express dev server. Anything that would let you swap out the express dev server for something else is a hack, in my opinion. I don't see any point in using anything else for development. Like I said, once you go into prod you can use anything you want by using the build command and just deploying the files. You DON'T want a server that runs in dev mode but is actually your production environment, but I feel like that's exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: No I don't want dev mode on production env.
As I write I want an app server that serve my development as well as production or staging env, so in feature I don't need to handle or setup server for production and staging.
Because if I go with  webpack dev server  then for staging/production I have to setup a server that's why I want to overcome from this situation. 

Here As per my thought the server will along with application no matter on which environment you are working just need to replace path of serving folder nothing else, hope it will more clear for you

Comment: With vue, unless you are using something like nuxt, there is no server-side code that needs to be executed. When running the build command you'll receive html, css and javascript, which any mainstream server can serve without additional setup. There is no backend logic running in vue that'd require you to setup anything with your prod server. If you still feel like there's too much configuration you could just wrap your code inside a docker container and deploy this.